# Why are my two computers running linux producing different results from C code

Tags: c, linux, complex-numbers

So I'm running some C code on a few different machines and on all of them except one I'm getting the same results. But on one machine, I am getting an incorrect value for Zth.

On my machine I get the correct value.  On the other machine I get 0.000 + 0.000 which is not right.  I'm guessing it has something to do with complex.h but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Are all of them 32bit or all of them 64bit?

Comment: Start by finding out what's different. Different architecture (32 vs 64 bit), different compiler version, different distro, different glibc version and so on.

Comment: one of the labels on the kernel is not the only identifying characteristic of a computer.

Comment: Can you edit and post more code?

Comment: Please show the output of `uname -a` from each system.  Also, what is the correct output?

Comment: I'll post more code when I get home today.  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: nevermind.  The problem has been fixed.  Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the expression down into smaller and smaller pieces until you find the problem.

Double check your compiler command and make sure it isn't using a different set of options for the build, such as `-ffast-math`.

Answer (score 0):

The floating point precision on different CPU models changes.

You should try using sizeof on float, double, long double and see if the results are the same.